# Is it possible to use bitmap index with more than two possible values?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes, bitmap-index

It clear how bitmap indexes works with two possible values (gender: male and female). But how is it possible to use with 3 or more values?
Can anyone explain how it works in postgresql?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20051226222915.G87624%40geri.cc.fer.hr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a *bitmap index*, it can do *bitmap index scans* over regular B-tree indexes.

For that it is not important how many values the indexed column (or columns) can have.

This is how it works:

- The index is scanned for the search condition.
- Rather than visiting the table for each row found, PostgreSQL builds a bitmap. This bitmap normally has one bit per table row, and the rows are sorted in physical address (`ctid`) order. The value of the bit indicates if that row matches the search condition or not (which has nothing to do with the value range of the indexed columns).

  If `work_mem` is too small to contain a bitmap with one bit per row, PostgreSQL degrades to storing one bit *per 8KB page*. This shows up as “lossy” entries in the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output and will lead to false positive hits in the next step which affects performance.
- During a second step, the *bitmap heap scan*, PostgreSQL visits the table and fetches (and re-checks, if necessary) all rows that show a hit in the bitmap.

The advantages of a bitmap index scan are:

- Even if many rows are selected, PostgreSQL has to visit each table block only once, and the rows are visited in physical order.
- Several bitmap index scans on the same table can be combined with a “bitmap AND” or a “bitmap OR” before the table is scanned. This can handle `OR`s efficiently and combine several conditions with `AND` if each of the conditions alone is not selective enough to warrant an index scan.